# Problem with inserting hex into byte array

Tags: go, hex

I'm trying to insert hex into byte array.

hex should be made of mac addr like below,
Not to convert mac address into hex, just add "0x" in front of each two number.
mac = "00:19:10:08:FE:08"
hex = 0x00, 0x19, 0x10, 0x08, 0xFE, 0x08

I made string slice like below to make hex array.

```
mac := "00:19:10:08:FE:08"
a := strings.Split(mac, ":")

for i, v := range a {
    a[i] = "0x" + v
}
fmt.Println(a) // output: [0x00 0x19 0x10 0x08 0xFE 0x08]
```

And i merge string slice into byte slice.

```
myByte := []byte{0x15, 0x1a}
myByte = append(myByte, a)
```

but error occurred like below,
"cannot use a (type []string) as type byte in append".

In short,
I want make byte array with mac address("00:19:10:08:FE:08").
byte array should be
[]byte{0x00, 0x19, 0x19, 0x08, 0xfe, 0x08}
How can I make this byte array automatically with Go?

Comment: First, you can't insert anything into arrays. Arrays are fixed-length. Second, you appear to actually be using slices, which can be resized.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I am using slices not array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `net.ParseMAC(mac)` try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/zgBCFRWAQ0F):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    mac := "00:19:10:08:FE:08"
    hw, err := net.ParseMAC(mac)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hw)
    // type HardwareAddr []byte
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert your strings (of the format `"0x12"`) to bytes. That may actually be easier if you don't put the `"0x"` prefix on. I suspect `strconf.ParseUint` woudl be the way to go.

Now, for MAC addresses, you are probably better off using `net.ParseMAC` as recommended by @wasmup, as there are multiple possible MAC formats (I have seen at least  12:34:56:78:9a:bc and 1234.5678.9abcd in the wild).